# How to adjust a color image like a scanned image

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-image, cifilter

I want to make a effect that a colored normal image to a scanned image.

like 2 pictures below, first image is the original image, second image is the adjusted image, effects should like the second image, the text on back of the page should also disappear:

*First image:*

[image: original image]

*Second image:*

[image: effected image]

I want to use CoreImage and CIFilter to do this. besides contrast and brightness. I think should adjust level like photoshop. but how can adjust that? or other method?

I have tried to adjust it in photoshop, it seems that use photoshop's level function can reach this effect, the value shows on picture below:

[image]

but I don't know how to do this use CIFilter or other methods? I don't want to import third part framework or sources. because iOS 11 Notes APP can reach this effect, I think system's methods and frameworks can do this.

Comment: What have you tried? What happened when you did?

Comment: I have add some explains in question.@matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below code.

```
func getScannedImage(inputImage: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    
    let openGLContext = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2)
    let context = CIContext(eaglContext: openGLContext!)
    
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
    let coreImage = CIImage(image: inputImage)
    
    filter?.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    //Key value are changable according to your need.
    filter?.setValue(7, forKey: kCIInputContrastKey) 
    filter?.setValue(1, forKey: kCIInputSaturationKey) 
    filter?.setValue(1.2, forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey) 
    
    if let outputImage = filter?.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage {
    let output = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent)
        return UIImage(cgImage: output!)
    }     
    return nil
}
```

You can call the above func like below.

```
filterImage.image = getImage(inputImage: filterImage.image!)
```

**Output:**  (Output from real Device)

[image]

---

For more understanding about `Core Image Filter` try below links and answers.

[Get UIImage from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43560442/get-uiimage-from-function/43563477#43563477) and [Convert UIImage to grayscale keeping image quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178846/convert-uiimage-to-grayscale-keeping-image-quality)

Core Image Filter Reference from Apple Doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html

**Note:** For more specific requirement you need to create your own custom filter. Following link may helps https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/10/20/ios-image-filters-in-swift/

---

Comment: Thanks for your code, it works for this picture, so I accept this answer. but if use other pictures, it may not works well. I am making effort to develop a common solution so that it can work for most of this kind of pictures. Auto make scanned picture. so if you have appropriate solution, please help me. Thanks very much.

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011332/cifilter-for-black-and-white-document/43011878#43011878 @Tolecen.

Comment: @Tolecen I believe you can easily  implement UISlider to Adjusts saturation, brightness, and contrast values manually to get the best result.hope this help...

Answer (score 0):

I believe in order to manually implement Photoshop-like level adjustment feature, you'll need to understand some of the core knowledge on the field of Image Processing.

You may want to read this `Core Image Programming Guide` as a starting point:

> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html

Or, you may simply end up using a third party framework, though you have already stated that you don't want to use 3rd party libraries. If this is the case, I would like to recommend `GPUImage2`, *just in case*:

> https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2

Finally, I found a similar question to this so you may want to take a look:

> [How can I map Photoshop's level adjustment to a Core Image filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765365/how-can-i-map-photoshops-level-adjustment-to-a-core-image-filter)

Good luck.