# How to create an image that looks photocopied on ios - Swift?

Tags: php, ios, arrays, image, core-image

I have taken an image and would like to some how get the effect/ appearance that the image was photocopied (please see below).
Is there any framework or filter that I can use?
Either in ios or php if I have to upload the image to process it to get the effect.

This is the image that I have captured:
[image]

This what I wold like to produce:

[image]

Comment: You can integrate some image editing library, supporting image filters and restrict it to particular filter matching your requirement.

Comment: @NileshPol please could you elaborate and maybe provide an answer.  I'm afraid that I am not too familiar with image editing.

Comment: https://github.com/kawoou/FlexibleImage here you can use `monochrome()` filter

Comment: check this post may help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397367/how-to-adjust-a-color-image-like-a-scanned-image/46405697#46405697

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use GPU Image library to make gray scale of the image. After gray scaling, the processed image gives a look that its photocopied.
https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage
But if you are expecting for any library to photocopy with retaining the color, I am afraid you have to write your own library to do so.

Comment: @johnDoe, if you have find this answer helpful, can you please accept it as answer, thanks.